# How to get all Element Types?

Tags: php, elementtype

From within a plugin/module using PHP; is there a way to query all element types being used, including custom elements?

I know in the `elements` database table there is a `type` column that I could potentially query. But I wasn't sure if there is a native Craft method I could take advantage of instead?

In an ideal world I just need an array of all the element types:

**Example:**

````php
['asset', 'category', 'entry', 'globalset', 'matrixblock', 'tag', 'user', 'single', 'event', 'product']```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found this:

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-getallelementtypes

```php
Craft::$app->getElements()->getAllElementTypes()
```

Comment: Whilst this mostly works, in my case it doesn't include `Solspace\Calendar\Elements\Event` which is in the `elements → types` column. But it does include `verbb\supertable\elements\SuperTableBlockElement` which isn't in the same database column. Seems a bit backwards, but currently doesn't impact what I wanted to acheive.